# Find the minimum possible difference between two arrays

Tags: python, algorithm, complexity-theory

I am struggling to figure out an efficient algorithm to perform the following task:

Given two arrays A and B with equal length, the difference between the two arrays is defined as:

```
diff = |a[0]-b[0]| + |a[1]-b[1]| +...+|a[a.length-1]-b[b.length-1]|
```

I am required to find the minimum possible difference between A and B, and I am allowed to replace at most one element from A with any other element in A. Note that you are not required to perform a replacement.

For example:

```
A = [1,3,5]
B = [5,3,1]
```

If we replace A[2] with A[0], then the difference between the two arrays is:

```
|1-5| + |3-3| + |1-1| = 4
```

This is the minimal possible difference between the two arrays. No other replacement of an element in A with another element in A would result in a smaller difference between A and B.

How would I go about solving this problem? I know how to solved the problem in O(n^2) (brute force), but struggling to figure out a more efficient way.

Thanks!

Comment: sorting will make it `nlogn`. will think if `n` is possible.

Comment: compute the `diff` equation you posted. check which element in A is closest to `diff`. Change accordingly. haven't thought if full proof but this should help you solve it in `n`.

Comment: You're not going to get an o(n log n)-time algorithm with only add/subtract/compare since there's a reduction from element distinctness.

Comment: @ShridharRKulkarni If I compute the diff and check which element is closest, I will get 3 or 5 in this case. How does that help?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat I ran my O(n^2) solution against some test cases and it timed out, therefore there is a faster way.

Comment: Yes, there's an O(n log n) algorithm along the lines that @ShridharRKulkarni suggested.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Do you have any idea how it might work? My original idea was to sort the array B, then perform a binary search on B for each element in A. You would do this to find the value in B that would give you the smallest possible sum for each element in A, keeping track of the indices (i,j) from the original arrays that would make this sum. Once you find the smallest sum, you can then simply replace a[j] with a[i]. However, this wont work if B has duplicated values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll implement Shridhar's suggestion of identifying the best modification for each element individually in O(n log n) time and taking the best one.

```
import bisect


def abs_diff(x, y):
    return abs(x - y)


def find_nearest(sorted_a, y):
    i = bisect.bisect(sorted_a, y)
    return min(
        sorted_a[max(i - 1, 0) : min(i + 1, len(sorted_a))],
        key=lambda z: abs_diff(z, y),
    )


def improvement(x, y, z):
    return abs_diff(x, y) - abs_diff(z, y)


def min_diff(a, b):
    sorted_a = sorted(a)
    nearest = [find_nearest(sorted_a, y) for y in b]
    return sum(map(abs_diff, a, b)) - max(map(improvement, a, b, nearest))


print(min_diff([1, 3, 5], [5, 3, 1]))
```

Comment: For `[4, 1, 5, 9]` and `[1,3,2,6]` it shows the difference as 8, it should be 7.

Comment: @Soumendra how do you figure? The absolute differences of corresponding elements before replacement are 3, 2, 3, 3, and the replacement zeroes out the first 3 for a total of 8.

Comment: 4 -3 = 1, 1 - 1 = 0, 5 - 2 = 3, 9 - 6 = 3; 1 + 0 + 3 + 3 = 7

Comment: ok, got it. you did before the replacement. I was searching for with replacement.

Answer (score 0):

This post mistakenly answers a variant of the question, which is to allow a single *swap* of two elements in A. I thought I'd leave it up since I worked on it.

Below are general possibilities for improvement. We can see that improvement happens when the pair we are swapping with has an opposite ordering (e.g., if `a1 < b1` then `a2 > b2` and vice versa). Looking more closely, we see the next quality is that the best candidate swap has the largest overlap with the first pair.

We can have an `O(n log n)` routine by first sorting all the given pairs by their lower element, then processing them in descending order of the lower element. As we descend, keep one order-statistic tree for the pairs where `a < b` and another for the pairs where `b ≤ a`. Order the trees by the higher element of each pair and keep two decorations: (1) the largest interval seen in the left subtree, and (2) the lowest lower element seen in the left subtree.

For each processed element, choose the larger overlap between (1) the pair in the opposite tree with an equal or lower high element and the largest interval (corresponding to the first tree decoration), and (2) the pair in the opposite tree with a higher than or equal high element and the lowest lower element (corresponding to the second tree decoration).

(Since we are processing the pairs in descending order of `low`, the seen `low`s will always be equal to or higher than the current element.)

(1)

```
Original:
     a1-----------b1
                     a2----b2
Total: -----------+----

Swapped:
     a1--------------------b2
                  b1-a2
Total: --------------------+-

Result: worse.
```

(2)

```
Original:
     a1-----------b1
                     b2----a2
Total: -----------+----

Swapped:
     a1--------------b2
                  b1-------a2
Total: --------------+-------

Result: worse.
```

(3)

```
Original:
     a1-----------b1
             a2------b2
Total: -----------+------

Swapped:
     a1--------------b2
             a2---b1
Total: --------------+---

Result: the same.
```

(4)

```
Original:
     a1-----------b1
             b2------a2
Total: -----------+------

Swapped:
     a1------b2
                  b1-a2
Total: ------+-

Result: BETTER.
Improvement: 2 * dist(b2, b1)
```

(5)

```
Original:
     a1--------------b1
           a2----b2
Total: --------------+----

Swapped:
     a1----------b2
           a2--------b1
Total: ----------+--------

Result: the same.
```

(6)

```
Original:
     a1--------------b1
           b2----a2
Total: --------------+----

Swapped:
     a1----b2
                 a2--b1
Total: ----+--

Result: BETTER.
Improvement: 2 * dist(b2, a2)
```

(7)

```
Original:
     a1--------------b1
 b2--------a2
Total: --------------+--------

Swapped:
 b2----a1
           a2--------b1
Total: ----+--------

Result: BETTER.
Improvement: 2 * dist(a1, a2)
```

(8)

```
Original:
     a1-----------b1
 b2-------------------a2
Total: -----------+-------------------

Swapped:
 b2--a1
                  b1--a2
Total: --+--

Result: BETTER.
Improvement: 2 * dist(a1, b1)
```